# Optimizing parallel nested loop with inner loop dependent on outer loop using openmp

Tags: c++, c, openmp

How do I get a better optimization for this piece of code using openmp. 
**Number of threads is 6**, but can't get better performance.

I have tried different scheduling options, but i can't get it optimized better.
Is there a way of getting a better result ?

```
int lenght = 40000;
int idx;
long *result = new long[ size ];

#pragma omp parallel for private(idx) schedule(dynamic)
for ( int i = 0; i < lenght; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++  ) {
        idx = (int)( someCalculations( i, j ) );
        #pragma omp atomic
        result[ idx ] += 1;
    }
}
```

This piece of code does optimize the calculation time, but I still need a better result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your currenct code you have a barrier just in the middle of the loop which kills all benefit from using multiple threads. You better split the workload into independent (!) parts, let each thread work on his part and only in the end accumulate the results

Comment: please only tag the language you are using, maybe your code could be both, but expecting that each answer covers two different languages is asking for too much

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thanks for the reply. That got it really optimized.

Comment: Also, provide a [mcve]. Chances are high that your best option is to optimize `someCalculations` on its own.

Comment: I think adding a `reduction` to your `result` in combination with joining the two `for` loops into one (such that you parallelize everything, as is the last task is the largest - assuming `someCalculations`always takes roughly the same amount of time) will be as good as you can do from the OpenMP perspective. After that all you can do is improve `someCalculations`.

Comment: A [mcve] is essential to answer the question because we cannot tell whether the performance bottleneck is in the atomic or `someCalculations`. Please include specific performance measurement results, compilation and execution instructions, as well as some system information (processor and memory specification).

Comment: Putting aside the other issues,  in dealing with a triangular loop you might use schedule(runtime) to facilitate testing guided or auto or dynamic, 2.  The maximum expected speedup over schedule (static) is 2.  NUMA con

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenMP 4.0 you can write your [own reduction](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-reduction.html).

The idea is :

- in `for` loop, you tell the compiler to reduce the place you modify in each loop.
- since omp doesn't know how to reduce such array, you must write your own adder `my_add` which will simply sum two array.
- you tell omp how to use it in your reducer (`myred`)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 40000

int someCalculations(int i, int j)
{
    return i * j % 40000  ;
}

/* simple adder, just sum x+y in y */
long *my_add(long * x, long *y)
{
    int i;
 #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < LEN; ++i)
    {
        x[i] += y[i];
    }

    free(y);
    return x;

}

/* reduction declaration:
   name
   type
   operation to be performed
   initializer */
#pragma omp declare reduction(myred: long*:omp_out=my_add(omp_out,omp_in))\
    initializer(omp_priv=calloc(LEN, sizeof(long)))

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    long *result = calloc(LEN, sizeof *result);

// tell omp how to use it
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(myred:result) private (i, j)
    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int idx = someCalculations(i, j);
            result[idx] += 1;
        }
    }

    // simple display, I store it in a file and compare 
    // result files with/without openmp to be sure it's correct...
    for (i = 0; i < LEN; ++i) {
        printf("%ld\n",  result[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Without `-fopenmp`: `real    0m3.727s`

With `-fopenmp`: `real    0m0.835s`

Comment: Actually, OpenMP also supports reducing C/C++ arrays at least since 4.5. The things is, we cannot know whether that actually helps in the question at hand or not due to the missing information.

Comment: It can't hurt, though I agree that wasting time optimizing parts of the code that are not problematic isn't the best way to spend your time. I still think merging these loops might be wise, or, at the very least, inverting the first loop such that you start with the longer tasks and then proceed to the easier ones. That way you can balance out the work between threads much more uniformly. Of course whether this is needed again depends on what these `someCalculations` are.